# How should I deal with a decimal value of LDPI version for an image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-icons

If I have an image with 22px in mdpi then the ldpi will be mdpi * 0.75 so 22*0.75
but the problem is the result will be a decimal value (16.5px in my case)

So should I make it 16px or 17px and does this small change make difference in the final result?

Thank you

Comment: If you care about it so much, why don't you check it yourself? Create an LDPI emulator and check it

Comment: Also the last LDPI device was manufactured ~5 years ago probably, so there are *probably* less than 0.01% LDPI devices, which are still supported. So probably you just care too much about it. If it was me, I'd just let Android to resize resources instead of me, and didn't create the LDPI resources at all

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.round

```
 int number = (int) Math.round(22*0.75);
 System.out.println(number); //output is 17
```

Comment: that's now that is asked in the question. Ahmed Alawdi asks how to size the LDPI resources correctly.